# Uncaught syntax error in Vue.js app with openweathermap API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fetch-api, web-frontend, openweathermap

I'm creating a vue.js weather app using OpenWeatherMap API and I have my key already. I fetch data from API but browser console displays a syntax error. When I tried using the API URL in Chrome browser, it shows data, but it doesn't show data in my app. Why?

My code:

```
export default {name: 'app', data () {
return {
  api_key: '72d3ff62f4ec547714c92c3b8cbd06c3',
  url_base: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/",
  query: '',
  weather: {}
}}, methods: {
fetchWeather (e) {
  if (e.key == "Enter") {
    fetch('${this.url_base}weather?q=${this.query}&units=metric&appid=${this.api_key}')
      .then(res => {
        return res.json();
      }).then(this.setResults);
  }
},
setResults (results) {
  this.weather = results;
} }}
```

Comment: What error is in the browser console?

Comment: @Saddy, Thanks for replying to my question. I have corrected the error already. My error was here - fetch('${this.url_base}weather?q=${this.query}&units=metric&appid=${this.api_key}'). Thanks a lot.